# Почему, перенося слова, нельзя от следующей гласной согласную отделять?

Tags: орфография

Почему, перенося слова, нельзя от следующей гласной согласную отделять (из-за чего группа 1. правильна, а 2. — некорректна)?

> 1. Мело-човка, да-чонка, би-дон.

> 2. Мелоч-овка, дач-онка, бид-он.

Comment: Слоговой принцип русской речи. Согласный и гласный тесно сливаются между собой и разделению не подлежат.